# What if my Red-White-Red Card plus expires before the 3 years period

Tags: residency, austria, passports

I am from a "Third country" (non EEA/EU) and have studied and worked (also currently residing) in Austria. I have applied for my [Red-White-Red Card plus](https://www.migration.gv.at/en/types-of-immigration/permanent-immigration/redwhiteredcardplus/), which should be valid for 3 years.

But my passport expires within the next 2 and half years. Do I have to leave the country or can I renew my plus card again? Because to apply for permanent residency, I need to complete 5 years and I would end up at 4 and half.

Answer (score 2):

You can renew the card by a similar process as when you initially applied for it, either with MA35 (Vienna) or your local Bezirkshauptmannschaft. A renewal process can be initiated 3 months before expiry of the current permit. There is no need to leave the country AS LONG AS you apply ***before*** your current permit expires.

See also the [official page](https://www.oesterreich.gv.at/themen/leben_in_oesterreich/aufenthalt/3/2/Seite.120307.html) of the Austrian federal government regarding the RWRK+.